# Prolog: How would I seperate a list into two lists depending on the category?

Tags: prolog

My query would be the following:

```
separate([eat(chips),drink(water),eat(burger),eat(banana),drink(coke)],food,drink).
food = [eat(chips),eat(burger),eat(banana)]
drink = [drink(water),drink(coke)]
```

I want to separate the list but I've not been able to figure out how to.

```
separate(X,Cat1,Cat2):-
     [Cat1|Cat2] = X,
     Cat2 = X,
     separate(X,Cat1,Cat2).
```

Currently I've been only able to use recursion to go through each element of the list but I don't really have any idea on how to start separating them into separate lists.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate question, but I just don't want to spend the time to find it.

Comment: @GuyCoder Feeling like a teaching assistant, are you? :-D

Comment: @DavidTonhofer `Feeling like a teaching assistant, are you?` No. Why do you say that.

Comment: @GuyCoder Because that's what a TA would say.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the higher-order *filter* operations taking a Goal for filtering:

- [`include/3`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=include/3)
- [`exclude/3`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=exclude/3)

For example (note that variables have to start with uppercase letters in Prolog):

```
separate(TaggedList,Food,Drink) :-
   include(isFood,TaggedList,Food),   % isFood/1 will be called for each element
   include(isDrink,TaggedList,Drink). % same as above

isFood(eat(_)).   % no need to be complex; just succeed if argument matches
isDrink(drink(_)).  % same as above
```

And so:

```
?- separate(
   [eat(chips),drink(water),eat(burger),eat(banana),drink(coke)],
   Food,Drink).
Food = [eat(chips), eat(burger), eat(banana)],
Drink = [drink(water), drink(coke)].
```

Comment: This solution traverses the list twice. One option would be to use partition/4 from the same library with either one of the two helper predicates you show in your solution.

Comment: @TA_intern Good idea. I need to remember. [`partition/4`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=partition/4) and [`partition/5`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=partition/5).

Answer (score 3):

Pattern matching. You want pattern matching.

When the list of food and drink is empty you have an easy base predicate:

```
separate([],[],[]).
```

When you want to separate out the food and drink it is as easy as this:

```
separate([eat(X)|T],[eat(X)|F],D) :- separate(T,F,D).
separate([drink(X)|T],F,[drink(X)|D]) :- separate(T,F,D).
```

When the head of the list matches `eat` then put the element on the first place of the `Food` list. When `drink` then on the `Drink` list. Simple.

When I run that:

```
?- separate([eat(chips),drink(water),eat(burger),eat(banana),drink(coke)],Food,Drink).
Food = [eat(chips), eat(burger), eat(banana)],
Drink = [drink(water), drink(coke)].
```

Answer (score 3):

Both answers are good as they are. Another option for SWI-Prolog would be to use `partition/4` like this:

```
separate(List, Eats, Drinks) :-
    partition(is_eat, List, Eats, Drinks).

is_eat(eat(_)).
```

Extra credit: why does this not work?

```
?- partition(eat(_),
             [eat(chips),drink(water),eat(burger),eat(banana),drink(coke)],
             Eats, Drinks).
```